# Taking PS4 controller input in python using Windows 10

Tags: python, arduino, windows-10

So im working on an idea where i take the input of a PS4 controller while im in a video game lets say (rainbow six siege) and while i play python can record my inputs. I’ve done some research and people have been able to record a PS4 controllers inputs but they were using linux and they were actively running the program while they were pressing buttons.

What I am trying to accomplish is take the inputs of a PS4 controller in a passive script (while i am running a video game) and to make it harder on myself I want to take those controller inputs and send them to an arduino where i can write if/else statements.

Im doing this as an exercise to be able to interface arduino and python (I’ve done it before on linux) and also see how to write a passive python script where its running and you don’t have to actively be on your command line or in your pycharm window.

I know i can get virtual box but is it possible without? And if its not can i run this in virtual box and alt+tab out of virtual box and run a Steam game?

Im running windows 10, PyCharm, Arduino IDE.

Answer (score 0):

although it have been a while since you have asked this question im going to answer it anyways for people who might need it.
I am working on a similar project where i need to take the ps4 controller inputs and use them to send commands to an arduino. and at first i tried to use a dedicated python library (pyPS4Controller) but i just couldent make to work on windows. subsequently after a little reserach i came accorose Pygame, it is normally a game libary but you can take controller inputs (and from what i could see it is not limited to only ps4 controller but it probably will work with most controllers) and use them in a diffrent task.

For more information and examples see python's [joystick documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/joystick.html).

Comment: Please link to official documentation sources when referring to them. "w3cub" is **not** pygame's official documentation source.